# Prove that the largest power of $2$ dividing $(n+1)(n+2) \cdots (an)$ is greater than$2^{(a-1)n}$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $a,n$ be positive integers. Find all $a$ such that for some $n$ the largest power of $2$ dividing $(n+1)(n+2) \cdots (an)$ is greater than $2^{(a-1)n}$.

Since I thought there were no such $a$, I thought about proving this by contradiction. That is, assume that $2^{(a-1)n+1}$ divides $(n+1)(n+2) \cdots (an)$. How can we get to a contradiction from here?

Answer (score 3):

There are $(a-1)n$ factors in the original expression.

$\lfloor \frac {(a-1)n + 1}{2}\rfloor$ are divisible by $2.$
$\lfloor\frac {(a-1)n + 1}{4}\rfloor$ are divisible by $4$.
$\lfloor\frac {(a-1)n + 1}{2^i}\rfloor$ are divisible by $2^i$

The largest power of $2$ that divides $(n+1)\cdots(an) = 2^{\left(\lfloor \frac {(a-1)n + 1}{2}\rfloor + \lfloor \frac {(a-1)n + 1}{2^2}\rfloor \cdots +\lfloor \frac {(a-1)n + 1}{2^i}\rfloor\cdots+\lfloor \frac {(a-1)n + 1}{2^{k}}\rfloor\right)}$

Where k is the largest integer $\le \log_2 ((a-1)n + 1) $

$\sum_\limits{i=1}^{k} \lfloor \frac {(a-1)n + 1}{2^i} \rfloor < ((a-1)n + 1)\sum_\limits {i=1}^{\infty} \frac 1{2^i}\\\sum_\limits {i=1}^{\infty} \frac 1{2^i} = 1\\
\sum_\limits{i=1}^{k } \lfloor \frac {(a-1)n + 1}{2^i} \rfloor < (a-1)n + 1\\
\sum_\limits{i=1}^{k } \lfloor \frac {(a-1)n + 1}{2^i} \rfloor \le (a-1)n$

Comment: I have added more detail..  Suppose $n = 3, a = 2,  (4\cdot 5 \cdot 6) = 120, 2^3| 120$ So, yes $2^{(a-1)n}$ can be a factor.

Comment: I think you mean the ceiling. Take for example $4,5,6,7,8$. The floor here would give $\left\lfloor\dfrac{6}{4}\right\rfloor = 1$.

Comment: You may have something there... I need to step out, and will give this another look tomorrow.

Comment: Whether it is floor or ceil depends on starting and ending term. In a sequence of $n$ consecutive integers you may have $\left\lfloor {n/2} \right\rfloor $  odd and $\left\lceil {n/2} \right\rceil $ even, or viceversa.

Comment: In light of the counter examples I outlined in my answer, I believe this answer is not valid anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Since $$(n+1)(n+2)...(an)=\frac{(an)!}{n!}$$
According to [Legendre's Theorem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/LegendresTheorem.shtml) 
$n!=2^{n-r_1}\cdot q_1$ where $r_1$-the number of $1$'s in binary expansion of $n$ and similarly $(an)!=2^{an-r_2}\cdot q_2$ and
$$\frac{(an)!}{n!}=\frac{q_2}{q_1}\cdot 2^{n(a-1)-r_2+r_1}$$

It is known (and not difficult to show) that multiplication by $2$ "shifts" the bits to the left, e.g. $(3)_{10}=(11)_2 \Rightarrow (2\cdot 3)_{10}=(110)_2$. Multiplying by $2^r$ shifts the bits $r$ times so that if $a=2^r$ then $an$ and $n$ will have the same number of $1$'s in binary representation, or $r_1=r_2$.

Re the contradiction, we don't want to have $r_1 > r_2$. But, let's assume $n=(11)_{10}=(1011)_2$ and $a=3$ then $an=(33)_{10}=(100001)_2$. 
$$11!=2^{11-3}\cdot 155925$$
$$33!=2^{33-2}\cdot 4043484860477916195764296875$$
or
[$$2^{11(3-1)+1} | 217535414131691079834009600000=\frac{33!}{11!}$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=217535414131691079834009600000%20%2F%202%5E(11(3-1)%2B1))
This is an example of $r_1 > r_2$.

**Update**

Few more examples:

- $an=129=2^7+1=3\cdot 43$, where $n=43$ [has $4$ of $1$'s in its binary representation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=43) and $129$ [only 2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=129).
- $an=2^9+1=513=27⋅19$ , where $19$ has $3$ of $1$'s and $27$ has $4$ of $1$'s.

Basically, looking at $an=2^{2k+1}+1$ (which always has 2 of $1$'s in its binary representation and is always divisible by $3$) will **always yield infinite examples**. This is easy to check, basically $2 \equiv -1 \pmod{3} \Rightarrow 2^{2k+1} \equiv (-1)^{2k+1} \equiv -1 \pmod{3}$, so 
$$an=2^{2k+1}+1=3\cdot n$$
$n$ will always (except a few exceptions) have more than $2$ of $1$'s in its binary representation, because:

- if $n$ has $1$ of $1$'s in its binary representation, then $n=2^t$, which will lead to $2 | 1$ contradiction, except the $t=0$ case **or $2^1+1=3$**.
- if $n$ has $2$ of $1$'s in its binary representation, then $n=2^t+2^z, t>z\geq0$. If $z>0$ then $2 | 1$ - contradiction. If $z=0$ then $2^{2k+1}+1=3\cdot (2^t+1)\Rightarrow 2^{2k}-3\cdot 2^{t-1}=1$. It $t>1$ then we have the same $2|1$ contradiction, thus $t=1$ and $2^{2k}=4$ or $k=1$ leading **to $2^3+1=3\cdot 3$**.

To conclude, apart for the two examples outlined above, $n$ will always have $\geq 3$ of $1$'s in its binary representation, while $an$ only $2$.

Comment: Is this the only one or are there others as well?

Comment: I just updated my answer with another example. Basically, looking at $an=2^{2k+1}+1$ (which always has 2 of $1$'s in its binary representation) may yield more examples.

Comment: $a=3$ is a particular example, but yes $2 \equiv -1 \pmod{3} \Rightarrow 2^{2k+1} \equiv (-1)^{2k+1}=-1 \pmod{3}$

Comment: So $a = 3$ is the only such $a$?

Comment: Not necessarily https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization#Sum.2Fdifference_of_two_nth_powers, $2^9+1=513=27\cdot 19$, where $19$ has $3$ of $1$'s and $27$ has $4$ of $1$'s.